# When forming an epoxide with m-CPBA, what happens when we wash our mixture with Na2S2O4?

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox, epoxidation

The m-CPBA is reduced by the $\ce{S2O4^{2-}}$, but why does it leave the mixture then?

Why does the reduced m-CPBA leave with the oxidised  $\ce{S2O4^{2-}}$?

Comment: The pKa of MCPBA is~7.6, the pKa of 3-Cl-benzoic acid is ~3.8 so is much easier to remove by an aq. base wash